# Where is this LightSail-2 trajectory data coming from? Is there more than TLEs available to the public?

Tags: trajectory, two-line-elements, historical-data, light-sail

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/M_R_Thomp/status/1168363775264788481) shows high granularity data for LightSail-2's perigee and apogee, showing that while the apogee-raising strategy is working nicely, currently atmospheric drag is taking its toll and the nominal altitude is just not quite high enough for the sail to provide overall orbit boost.

**Question:** While the discontinuities look like they could be coming from TLE updates every day or so, the data points themselves look too dense. Is this data from TLEs or is there a higher granularity source for LightSail-2's trajectory? Perhaps self-reported GPS fixes or [laser ranging](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27945/12102)? Is there more than TLEs available to the public?

---

[image: orbital evolution of LightSail2]

[image: orbital evolution of LightSail2]

> The orbital evolution of #LightSail2 still looking the same.  Rising apogee, lowering perigee, orbital energy falling slowly. If you squint, the energy is falling at a bit of a slower rate lately, but that's probably due to being on the good side of a monthly perturbation.